# Take unique and new values ​from the array with duplicate data

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I have this scenario:

```json
const data = [
    {
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640371815, // 15:50:15
    },{
       "name": "Brien",
       "timestamp": 1640373855, // 16:24:15
    },{
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640363601 // 13:33:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356701 // 11:38:21
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356521 // 11:35:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356401 // 11:33:21
   }
];
```

I need to get lasted one from duplicates by timestamp:

```json
   // expected result
    [
       {
         "name": "Hebert",
         "timestamp": 1640371815 // 15:50:15 newest one
       },{
         "name": "Brien",
         "timestamp": 1640373855 // 16:24:15 unique
       },{
         "name": "Mary",
         "timestamp": 1640356701 // 11:38:21 newest
       }
    ];
```

I try this:

```js
    data.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        .filter((chat, index, self) => self.findIndex( c => c.name == chat.name ) == index )
```

output duplicated removed but no considering newest timestamp between each duplicates

Comment: Sort by timestamp first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than sorting and using filter you can iterate the array just once storing items in a Map or object using the names as keys and then just update the lowest timestamp as you loop through each item.

Then finally convert the object values back to array

```js
const items = new Map()

data.forEach(({name,timestamp}) => {  
  const o = items.get(name);
  if(o){
    timestamp < o.timestamp && o.timestamp = timestamp;    
  } else {
     items.set(name, {name, timestamp});
  }
});

const res = [...items.values()]

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>

const data = [
    {
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640371815, // 15:50:15
    },{
       "name": "Brien",
       "timestamp": 1640373855, // 16:24:15
    },{
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640363601 // 13:33:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356701 // 11:38:21
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356521 // 11:35:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356401 // 11:33:21
   }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
    {
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640371815, // 15:50:15
    },{
       "name": "Brien",
       "timestamp": 1640373855, // 16:24:15
    },{
       "name": "Hebert",
       "timestamp": 1640363601 // 13:33:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356701 // 11:38:21
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356521 // 11:35:21 
    },{
       "name": "Mary",
       "timestamp": 1640356401 // 11:33:21
   }
];

const seen = {};
const dataModified = [];

data.forEach((elem) => {
  const index = seen[elem.name];
  
  if(index == undefined){
    dataModified.push(elem);
    seen[elem.name] = dataModified.length - 1;
  } else if(dataModified[index].timestamp < elem.timestamp){
    dataModified.splice(index, 1, elem);
  }
});

console.log(dataModified);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
.filter((chat, index, self) => self.findIndex(c => c.name === chat.name && c.timestamp > chat.timestamp)<0)
```

The idea is that findIndex would only return the index when there exists another duplicate with greater timestamp, else it'd return -1.